# Right syntax to start a jquery plugin out of these 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

This is my first attempt at a jquery plugin and I've looked at a few tutorials that do it differently. I'm pasting 3 methods below and my question is: are there any problems with any of these methods, or any reasons why I should follow or not follow one of those methods? I thought `this.each(function()` in the second example was interesting so I'm inclined to follow this example, but not sure. Looking for more expert advice.

First example I saw starts the plugin like this, **where xyz is the plugin name**

```
new function($) {
    $.fn.xyz = function(settings) {
        settings = settings || {};

        return ////;
    };
}(jQuery);
```

Second tutorial from [here](http://www.queness.com/post/112/a-really-simple-jquery-plugin-tutorial) says this is the way to do it

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        xyz: function() { 
            //Iterate over the current set of matched elements
            return this.each(function() {             
                //plugin code             
            });
        }
    });  
})(jQuery);
```

and 3rd one starts it like this

```
jQuery.fn.center = function(){
   var element = $(this);

   xyz();

   function xyz(){
     //plugin code
   }     
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't go far wrong than jQuery's official doc on authoring a plugin - http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring